# Python saves objects like R and Matlab

Tags: python, matlab

Suppose we want to save some objects after computation, say, `a`,`b`and`c`.

In R and Matlab we can do this respectively by

```r
# save.image(file="R_out.RData") #save everything in R session
save(a,b,c,file="R_out.RData") #the objects you do want to save
```

and

```matlab
% save('Matlab_out.mat')  %save everything in Matlab session
save('Matlab_out.mat','a','b','c')  %the objects you do want to save
```

How can we achieve similar goals in Python?

Comment: You might want `pickle`.

Comment: I think following might be useful read for you https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/serialization/

Comment: Very good suggestions! @LeopardShark

Comment: Impressive and abundant  solutions!  @Daweo